# View's change automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, view

I would like to know how can i change a view to another view automatically. Like a presentation thing to start my app.

Could someone help me here?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want your app do?

Comment: before i start the main view, i want to show an image, but this image must change to the main view automatically, understood?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `NSTimer` to schedule the execution of a method of your class that will display  your views by calling `addSubview`.

Something along the lines of:

```
    self.slideshowTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(showNextSlide)
                                                     userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

as to adding/removing the view, you have plenty of options; one very simple scheme is associating a tag to your "slide" view and then do:

```
- (void)showNextSlide {

   UIView* current_view = [self.view viewWithTag:SLIDE_VIEW_TAG];
   if (current_view) [current_view removeFromSuperview];
   current_view = <ALLOCATE YOUR NEXT VIEW>
   [self.view addSubview:current_view];
}
```

This is just an example, you may find better ways to manage your views.

Don't forget to call `invalidate` on your NSTimer when you are done with it (possibly in your class `dealloc` method).